# What is the proper way of utilizing inline FTP links to files?

Tags: php, laravel, url, ftp

I am presented with a string that I need to use to download an image...

```
ftp://FTPUSER:FTPPASS@HOST.COM\Path\To\File.jpg
```

and I'm wondering if there's a better way to use this string, rather than using regex/parse_url to cut it up and enter the info into a traditional FTP ftp_connect, ftp_login,ftp_pasv, etc, etc...

Maybe like an

```
 ftp_get_file(ftp://FTPUSER:FTPPASS@HOST.COM\Path\To\File.jpg)
```

or something like that.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: it's a url, so why not [parse_url](http://php.net/parse_url)?

Comment: Updated post, thanks.

Comment: well, why re-invent the wheel with your own parsing function when parse_url is designed for this? it's already dotted all the i's and crossed all the t's, where you'd be starting from scratch and spend more time debugging/testing than actually getting anything useful done.

Comment: I think you're getting a little side tracked. I do agree with you, but my question isn't related to *how* i break it up, i'm asking for an alternative to *having* to break it up.

Comment: what other alternative is there? you need to split out the individual parts for those various functions ANYWAYS, since php itself won't accept this url as arguments for ANY of those functions. so one way or another, you'll be doing some splitting.

Comment: *"what other alternative is there?"* is exactly my question.

Comment: there isn't any. if you're using the built-in php ftp functions. you have to confirm to what they exepect for inputs, which means you HAVE to split up your url. and then you might as well just use parse_url...

Comment: There is though, you should be able to use `fopen('ftp://FTPUSER:FTPPASS@HOST.COM\Path\To\File.jpg'` to get the file resource.

Comment: ^^ Thank you @user3158900, that works! I'll submit a full function answer shortly....

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @user3158900, working solution is ....

```
function downloadFileViaFTPURL($remote_data)
{
    // I dunno why, but this made it work...
    $search_replace = ["\\" => "/"];

    foreach ($search_replace as $search => $replace) {
        $remote_data = str_replace($search, $replace, $remote_data);
    }

    if ($remote_data = fopen($remote_data, "r")) {
        $filename = explode("/", $remote_data);
        $filename = end($filename);

        if (!file_exists("/path/to/folderforfile")) {
            mkdir("/path/to/folderforfile", 0755, true);
        }

        if (file_put_contents("/path/to/folderforfile/$filename", $remote_data)) {

            return true;

        }
    }
    return false;
}

downloadFileViaFTPURL("ftp://FTPUSER:FTPPASS@HOST.COM\Path\To\File.jpg");
```

Hope this helps someone!